# Placing columns inside bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a Bootstrap model to have multiple columns inside it, however it does not appear to be working with my content appear vertically as opposed to in columns. My code is here:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="row-md-6">
                        Left
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-md-6">
                        Right
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've found a few things around that solved this issue with Bootstrap 2, but they don't work with Bootstrap 3. I've also tried changing the `row-md-6` to `sm`, `xs` etc, but no luck. Is it possible to do it in Bootstrap 3? Columns would be the most ideal thing for me, but should I avoid columns all together?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is no `row-md-*` in Bootstrap, but `col-md-*` should work..

```
    <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              Left
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              Right
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/130819

Comment: Arghhh! I'm an idiot! Thanks haha, think its always good to get another person to look over code as you always miss things.

Comment: Even I write this basic code  for my model, I am getting two columns aligned vertically instead of horizontal scheme.Is there any common reason for this?